# Office 365 Management API always returning last 24 hours data

Tags: office-365, audit-log-reports

I am trying to fetch audit log data from Office 365 using O365 Managment Activity APIs. I am facing this issue that all my requests are returning data for last 24 hours, even when I pass a startTime & endTime in the original request.

Below is the url I am forming for my request. Here I am trying to get data for last 3 hours. I also tried the same with last 3 days but same result.

> https://manage.office.com/api/v1.0//activity/feed/subscriptions/content?PublisherIdentifier=&contentType=Audit.SharePoint&startTime=2017-11-24T13:52:43.6236735Z&endTime=2017-11-24T16:52:45.0966735Z

In my response I get a nextpage URI but it has starttime & endtime as last 24 hours.

Any help is much appreciated!